# how to convert bytes to string in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to write a function that returns a string, not bytes.
  the function:

```
def read_image(path):
    with open(path, "rb") as f:
        data = f.read()
    return data
image_data = read_image("/home/user/icon.jpg")
```

How to convert the value `image_data` to type str.
If convert to string successfully, how to reconvert the string to bytes.

Comment: So why can't you just apply `str()` to whatever you want to return?

Comment: <byte object>.decode("utf-8")

Comment: @Primusa,<byte object>.decode("utf-8") throw exception.```UnicodeDecodeError:'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff```

Comment: I don't think you can make a string out of a jpg image.  What are you planning on doing with it?

Comment: In order to adapte Python 2. Some libs use my function, but the libs writen with Python 2.@PatrickHaugh

Comment: Why is this flagged as a duplicate? These two questions aren't the same, you can't decode an image's bytes.

Answer (score 15):

In order to be compatible with older code you want to return a string object the way it was back in python2 and convert a bytes object to a string object.

There might be an easier way, but I'm not aware of one, so I would opt to do this:

```
return "".join( chr(x) for x in data)
```

Because iterating bytes results in integers, I'm forcibly converting them back to characters and joining the resulting array into a string.

In case you need to make the code portable so that your new method still works in Python2 as well as in Python 3 (albeit might be slower):

```
return "".join( chr(x) for x in bytearray(data) )
```

Bytearray itterates to integers in both py2 and py3, unlike bytes.

*Hope that helps.*

**Wrong approach:**

```
return data.decode(encoding="ascii", errors="ignore")
```

There might be ways to register a custom error handler, but as it is by default you are going to be missing any bytes that are outside the ascii range. Likewise using the UTF-8 encoding will mess your binary content.

**Wrong approach 2**

```
str(b'one') == "b'one'" #for py3, but "one" for py2
```

Comment: Consider base64 encoding instead of mapping chars

Comment: Or:  `return "".join(map(chr,data))`